Using Reactivity in Screenflow with UnofficialSF Datatable and Apex-Defined Object
I'm struggling to get reactivity to work between the UnofficialSF Datatable (latest version) and a Display Text component (contrived to demonstrate the issue).
Quick note: I have not used reactive screen flow elements before, so my base assumption that this should work could well be wrong.
At a high level, I am trying to create a documented picklist (akin to the Record Type selection screen) using a single-select datatable which displays the selected value to the user and hides.
Skipping over how I get the list of picklist values (which was a journey in and of itself), let's assume I get a Serialized list of [{label:"",value:"",description""}]
I created the datatable as such:



With the following outputs mapped to variables:

I added a Display Text component which holds several attempts to dynamically reference the selected value.

Now, when I debug the flow and select a value nothing happens.

So, my post is two parts:

Should the Display Text update upon selection in the UnofficialSF Datatable? (Read: is my understanding of reactive screenflows accurate?)
If so, what am I doing wrong?


Since you're using an UnofficialSF component, you should to check with their support resources and their Trailblazer group.
